# Finding if two objects collide

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, vectors, collision

The question that I'm trying to understand is this:

[image]

This is the part of the solution I don't understand:

[image]

From my knowledge, if $v_p-v_q$ is due south, this means $r_p-r_q$ is also due south, which means the objects will collide, but I'm not sure. So I was wondering if my reasoning is correct or if there is another reasoning to this part of the solution.

Comment: that is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relative to Q, Q is not moving, and P is north of Q. $\vec v_p - \vec v_q$ is the velocity of P relative to Q. So basing on that, and knowing that P is exactly north of Q initially, we only need to know if P is going south relative to Q.

Also, this means that $r_p-r_q$, the position of P relative to Q, is due north. Then, we should expect the velocity of P relative to Q, $\vec v_p - \vec v_q$, to be exactly due south for them to collide.

Answer (score 0):

Your explanation is almost exactly the same as the one which you say that you do not understand. So what exactly is confusing you?

If $v_p-v_q$ is due south it does not necessarily follow that $r_p-r_q$ is also due south.  For example, Q could be stationary while P moves due south, but the initial position of P could still be east or west or even south of Q instead of north of Q.  In the 1st three cases (P east or west or south of Q) P will not collide with Q; only in the 3rd case (P north of Q) will P collide with Q.